# C# search large text file quickly

Tags: c#, parsing, search, text

I have browsed a view related articles, but haven't quite found a solution that fits my query.
In a large plain-text File (~150MB, ~1.800.000 lines) I quickly want to find specific lines that have certain features using C#.

Each line has 132 characters, every one has a region-, a section-, a subsection code and an ident.
The combination of these 4 characteristics is unique.
Depending on the section code, the exact location of the other parts may differ.

Essentially, I want to retrieve up to ~50 elements with one method, that ideally takes less than a second.

The code I have so far works, but is way to slow for my purposes (~29 seconds of execution for 30 entries):

```
//icaoCode is always 2 char long
public static List<Waypoint> Retrieve(List<(string ident, string icaoCode, char sectionCode, char subSectionCode)> wpData)
        {
            List<Waypoint> result = new List<Waypoint>();

            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataFile);
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string data = reader.ReadLine();
                if (data.Length != 132) continue;

                foreach(var x in wpData)
                {
                    int subsPos = (x.sectionCode, x.subSectionCode) switch
                    {
                        ('P', 'N') => 5,
                        ('P', _) => 12,
                        (_, _) => 5
                    };

                    if (data[4].Equals(x.sectionCode) && data[subsPos].Equals(x.subSectionCode))
                    {
                       //IsNdb() and others look at the sectionCode and subSectionCode to determine data type
                        if (IsNdb(data) && data[13..17].Trim() == x.ident && data[19..21] == x.icaoCode) result.Add(ArincHelper.LoadNdbEntry(data));

                        else if (IsVhf(data) && data[13..17].Trim() == x.ident && data[19..21] == x.icaoCode) result.Add(ArincHelper.LoadVhfEntry(data));
                        else if (IsTacan(data) && data[13..17].Trim() == x.ident) result.Add(ArincHelper.LoadTacanEntry(data));
                        else if (IsIls(data) && data[13..17].Trim() == x.ident && data[10..12] == x.icaoCode) result.Add(ArincHelper.LoadIlsEntry(data));
                        else if (IsAirport(data) && data[6..10] == x.ident && data[10..12] == x.icaoCode) result.Add(ArincHelper.LoadAirportEntry(data));
                        else if (IsRunway(data) && (data[6..10] + data[15..18].Trim()) == x.ident && data[10..12] == x.icaoCode) result.Add(ArincHelper.LoadRunwayEntryAsWaypoint(data));
                        else if (IsWaypoint(data) && data[13..18].Trim() == x.ident && data[19..21] == x.icaoCode) result.Add(ArincHelper.LoadWaypointEntry(data));
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();

            return result;
        }
```

IsNdb() and the other identifying Methods all look like this:

```
private static bool IsNdb(string data) => (data[4], data[5]) == ('D', 'B') || (data[4], data[5]) == ('P', 'N');
```

Some Example data lines would be:

```
SEURPNEBBREB OP    EB004020HOM  N50561940E004353360                       E0010           WGEBRUSSELS                      169641609
SEURP EDDFEDAFRA     0FL100131Y N50015990E008341364E002300364250FFM ED05000          MWGE    FRANKFURT/MAIN                331502006
SEURD        CHA   ED011535VDHB N49551597E009022334CHA N49551597E009022334E0020005292  249WGECHARLIE                       867432005
SEURP LFFKLFCFK404 LF0    W F   N46262560W000480430                       E0000     WGE           FK404                    331071909
```

I would like to avoid loading the whole file into memory, as this takes ~400MB of RAM, although it is possible of course.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit:
The current solution converts this data file into an SQLite DB, which is then used.
This however takes ~3h of converting the file into the DB, which I want to avoid, as the data file is regularily swapped out.
This is why I would like to give this text parsing a try.

Comment: Have you considered loading the file into something that is better suited for querying, like a database?

Comment: Do you know approximately records you have to read to get the required amount of elements?

Comment: The list of parameters can be up to approximately 50 entries long, the code just retrieves all of them.

Comment: Unfortunately no, as they are not necessarilly ordered..

Comment: The current solution converts this to a SQLite DB, but I would like to go away from that, as it would make swapping out the data files easier.
Converting one takes ~3h, which is kind of annoying.

Comment: First you should start by measuring your parsing overhead. If the overhead is a low percentage, the only way to speed this up will be reading lines in parallel.

Assuming you still need to speed up your loop, I have a couple of suggestions. Hoist everything that you can out of your foreach loop, and into the main loop. eg `var ident =data[13..17].Trim();`

Then I would rearrange those nested if tests to perform the fastest tests first. The quicker you can reject any test, the better.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will take that into consideration.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Presumably that means `wpData` contains up to 50 elements, and only those that match will be added to `result`.

Comment: I think your problem is you are matching each line against the (up to 50?) elements of `wpData` so you have an O(n*m) process (where n = number of lines and m = number of `wpData` elements). Since each line can only be of one type, I would suggest inverting the processing to determine line type, and then attempt matches against `wpData`.

Comment: Can you provide a (web) source for the full file? Can you provide the definitions for the remaining test `Is`... methods?

Answer (score 0):

As @mjwills suggest there are better suited tools for the job, I would keep this data in a database. If I was going to try and make your current code faster I would try the following. I would read chunks of the data into an array, and process that part of the in a parallel for loop, and exit the loop when you have enough elements. Below is some pseudo code to get you started. I can't write complete code because I don't have you object/file.

```
List<Waypoint> result = new List<Waypoint>();

var max = 1800000; //set the to the max rows in your file
var allLines = new string[max];
var dataFile = "";

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(dataFile))
{
    int x = 0;
               
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        allLines[x] = sr.ReadLine();
        x += 1;

        if (x % 5000 == 0)
        {
             var i = x - 5000;
             Parallel.For(i, allLines.Length, x =>
             {
                //do your process here and exit if you have enough elements also set
                //a flag to exit the while loop
             });
        }

        //you would have to write some code to handle the last group of records that are less than 5k
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will give that a try.
As I just commented above, the current solution actually uses a conversion to SQLite, but this takes 3h per file, which is regularly swapped out, which is why I want to try to use the raw data file.

Comment: Your SQLite load should be much faster than that. I can load very large files quickly using bulk inserts.

Comment: That is true, the SQLite implementation is very good.
This is more a "try to see if I can match performance at all" kind of thing.

Comment: @mjwills sorry - I was wondering auto fill wasn't working...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Gigantor for this which should be many times faster.  Gigantor is a c# library for doing fast regex searching of gigantic files.  It is available as either [source code](https://github.com/imagibee/Gigantor) or [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Imagibee.Gigantor/#readme-body-tab).

Gigantor's search benchmark searches 5 GBytes in about 3 seconds finding a total of 105160 matches.

You would just need to convert your parsing code to a regular expression instead.